# printpreview not showing properly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, print-preview

I have a form clicking the print preview button showing as a preview of the form but it's displaying like screenshot.because it's showing background gray color background and textview boxes also displaying.
[In the below preview it's looks like a screenshot and don't want to show textboxes only want to show values]

```
Private Sub Button4_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings
        PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
        If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings

            PrintDocument1.Print()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview

        Button4.Visible = False
        Button5.Visible = False
        Button1.Visible = False
        Button2.Visible = False
        PrintForm1.Print()

    End Sub
```

Comment: can u please clarify ur the problem?

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `PrintDocument` and a `PrintForm`. The point of a `PrintForm` is to print the form. If that's not what you want then don't use one. Use a `PrintDocument` and then draw only what you want printed in the `PrintPage` event handler.

Comment: when clicking the printview button showing only half of the form.and textbox borders also displaying.

Comment: Hi jjmcilhinney see my comment